# How to communicate with salt-master

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to access salt master from salt-minion. But, I am unable to get the keys on salt-master.

On my VM, I installed `salt-master` and on my Windows, I installed `salt-minion`. I have given master IP address on my minion vi salt\conf\minion

```
master: master ip address
```

I tried to run the command below:

```
c:\salt\salt-minion.exe -l debug -c c:\salt\conf
```

I am getting a message like below:

```
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from c:\salt\conf\minion
[INFO    ] Using cached minion ID from c:\salt\conf\minion_id: HoroppaLabs
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: c:\salt\conf\minion
[INFO    ] Setting up the Salt Minion "HoroppaLabs"
[DEBUG   ] Created pidfile: c:\salt\var\run\salt-minion.pid
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from c:\salt\conf\minion
[DEBUG   ] Attempting to authenticate with the Salt Master at 172.31.16.131
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: c:\salt\conf\pki\minion\minion.pem
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: c:\salt\conf\pki\minion\minion.pem
[WARNING ] SaltReqTimeoutError: Waited 60 seconds
[INFO    ] Waiting for minion key to be accepted by the master.
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: c:\salt\conf\pki\minion\minion.pem
[WARNING ] SaltReqTimeoutError: Waited 60 seconds
[INFO    ] Waiting for minion key to be accepted by the master.
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: c:\salt\conf\pki\minion\minion.pem
```

I didn't get anything else, just the above.

On master, I tried to run the below command

```
sudo salt-key -L
Accepted Keys:
Unaccepted Keys:
Rejected Keys:
```

I didn't get any keys on master to accept

Can any one help, how can I communicate with salt-master?

Comment: Is there a firewall blocking ports 4505 and/or 4506 from your salt minion to your salt master (you can checking using a port scan on windows).

Comment: Are you able to telnet from the minion to the ip you specified as master in minion configuration file? Try to telnet to the ip on ports 4505 and 4506. If you are unable to telnet then there seems to be some sort of firewall on your master that's blocking port 4505 and 4506. These ports need to be open for the minions to be able to contact the master.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to default incoming port on master (4505 and 4506) for salt communication are blocked
Since minions connect to masters, the only firewall configuration that must be done is on the master. By default master must be able to accept incoming connection on port 4505 and 4506 
If your master is on centos or RHEL try below command to add ports to your firewall settings 
1. firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
It will say either public, dmz, or something else. 
You should only apply to the zones required.

2. firewall-cmd --permanent --zone= --add-port=4505-4506/tcp 
   firewall-cmd --reload   (to open port 4505 and 4506)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your salt minion to your master. To do that run following command on you master:

`salt-key -A <your_minions_hostname_or_ip>`

For example in my case I did

`salt-key -A virtual@192.168.56.101`

For reference have a look [here](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/walkthrough.html#using-salt-key).