# How can I generate a Salt minion key pair using OpenSSL?

Tags: salt-stack

I am building a [Chef cookbook](http://github.com/darylrobbins/chef-salt) to setup [Salt](http://www.saltstack.com) and manage the key exchange between minions and masters.

I am aware that the Salt minion will automatically generate the keys at `/etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.{pem,pub}` when it first starts, but I cannot depend on the timings of when the information will be available in the script.

From the [Salt documentation](http://salt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/tutorials/preseed_key.html), I could generate the keys on the master with `salt-key --gen-keys=[key_name]`. However, for security reasons, I'd rather the key be generated on the minion, so only the public key ever needs leave the machine.

The keys looks like fairly standard RSA keys. What would be the parameters to openssl or ssh-keygen to generate a key that would be accepted by Salt? I am just looking for the bit length and other parameters that Salt is looking for in such a key.

Thanks very much!

Comment: are you asking about the ssh key-pair?

Comment: I don't believe it is an ssh key per se. I am referring to the contents of /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem and /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pub, which the master uses to authenticate a minion for all communication.

Comment: Have you already done http://stackoverflow.com/a/25156098/1903108?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have no issue getting the master and minion talking in the standard case. My question is a more advanced case. Internally, the minion uses an OpenSSL library to generate its own key on initial startup using various encryption parameters. What I am trying to do is generate the minion's key in my script instead, because I am automatically scripting the execution of `ssh-key -A` on the master. To do that, I need to know which exact encryption parameters are being used to generate the key in the first place.

Comment: Just curious, why are you doing that? Is it usually better to use Salt to provision and control Chef client. It doesn't make any sense for my to do the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `salt-key` to create the key.

```
[me@elsapo ~]$ sudo salt-key --gen-keys=minion02 --gen-keys-dir=/tmp/testkey

return:
    37:6e:6d:42:ba:c6:da:1d:46:28:fb:bc:ce:27:10:13:7c:a2:d8:de:f9:d5:ba:6a:01:4a:f4:72:ad:bd:1b:20

[me@elsapo ~]$ ls /tmp/testkey

minion02.pem  minion02.pub
```

Then you can move the pem and pub key files to wherever you want them.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue, using Salt inside Vagrant. The correct solution is of course always going to be to run

```
salt-key --gen-keys=master
```

In my case, however, the keys need to be generated on the host machine (where Salt is not installed) but the Vagrant salt provisioner expects to find them so it can copy them to the new VM.

You can generate them with OpenSSL. Generate the private key with:

```
openssl genrsa -out master.pem
```

and then the public key with:

```
openssl rsa -in master.pem -pubout -out master.pub
```

The keys generated this way seem to have the same defaults as those generated by salt-key, but YMMV.

Comment: You have saved me, sir! 2 hours I spent figuring out why this tutorial: https://docs.mirantis.com/mcp/q4-18/mcp-operations-guide/saltstack-operations/salt-master-cert/replace-ssh-rsa.html doesn't work for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code is in salt/crypt.py: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/2014.1/salt/crypt.py#L88

Looks like it uses `from M2Crypto import RSA` and then later `gen = RSA.gen_key(keysize, 65537, callback=lambda x, y, z: None)`

M2Crypto is a wrapper around OpenSSL.

M2Crypto.RSA.gen_key is defined here: https://github.com/M2Crypto/M2Crypto/blob/master/M2Crypto/RSA.py#L314

Returns M2Crypto.RSA.RSA object.

It wasn't easy finding the keysize, it defaults to 4096 in config.py:
https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/1bfed117560fbde11c88ad7a013be76dc6eadf0f/salt/config.py#L409

The public key is saved in PEM format.

So it looks like you could do it with OpenSSL.  I've not verified this.